# Extending a Widget Loaded from a UI File

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I'd like to be able to load a widget (QMainWindow in this case) from a `.ui` file, but also be able to extend the class so that I can do things like catch keyboard events.

For example, I have the following that doesn't work but shows what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.window = QUiLoader().load("mainwindow.ui", self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.window)

        self.window.keyPressEvent = self.key_pressed
        self.window.setEnabled(True)

    def show(self):
        self.window.show()

    def key_pressed(self, event):
        print(event)
```

Because I cannot extend the object loaded from `QUiLoader`, I attempted to hijack the `keyPressEvent` method in that object, and assign it to my own `key_pressed` method. This doesn't work, but I'm unsure how else to go about capturing keyboard events.

I know I could create `MyMainWindow` and set it's base class to `QMainWindow`, and then override the `keyPressEvent` method, but then I have to do all the layout in code, and I'd much rather leverage the `.ui` file. How do you go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To listen to events from other widgets you must use an eventFilter. Also the initial window is never displayed so it is better to replace it with a QObject.

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtUiTools

class MyApp(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.window = QtUiTools.QUiLoader().load("mainwindow.ui")
        self.window.installEventFilter(self)

    def show(self):
        self.window.show()

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.window:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
                print(event.key())
        return super(MyApp, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyApp()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: so there is no way to override `keyPressEvent`? I'm going to want to track mouse events as well, and it'll be slightly cleaner if I can have one method for key press, and another for mouse events. Just wondering the idiomatic way to go about this... thanks!

Comment: @wspeirs If you really need to separate the two, there is nothing stopping you from creating 2 functions that take `obj` and `event` arguments. Add the keyPress/mouse logic in those functions and call them in the event filter in the appropriate spots.